# How to suppress a specify error in RxSwift?

Tags: fatal-error, rx-swift, suppress

When run in Debug scheme, there is a fatal error in line 30, if you code are something like this.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxSwift/Observables/Implementations/Sink.swift

```
rxFatalError("Warning: Recursive call or synchronization error!")
```

If I choose run scheme from Debug to Release. The fatal error won't show. But I wonder if I could do something to suppress it.

```
class ViewController4: UIViewController {
    var v = Variable(0)
    var disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    var notiBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        v.asObservable()
            .subscribe(onNext: { _ in
                let noti = Notification(name: MyNotificationName)
                NotificationCenter.default.post(noti)
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        NotificationCenter.default.rx.notification(MyNotificationName)
            .subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] _ in
                if self.v.value == 10 { self.notiBag = DisposeBag() }
                else { self.v.value += 1 } // this line cause the issue
                print(self.v.value)
                self.counterTextView.text! += "\(self.v.value)\n"
            })
            .disposed(by: notiBag)
        v.value = 0
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var counterTextView: UITextView!
}

let MyNotificationName = Notification.Name.init(rawValue: "My Notification Name")
```

Comment: It looks like your code is listening for the notification `MyNotificationName` and then reposting it 10 times? Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fatal error appears only in debug mode because it calls rxFataError only when you compile for debug. Its defined like this:

```
#if DEBUG
    if AtomicIncrement(&_numberOfConcurrentCalls) > 1 {
        rxFatalError("Warning: Recursive call or synchronization error!")
    }

    defer {
        _ = AtomicDecrement(&_numberOfConcurrentCalls)
    }
#endif
```

I just got this fatal error after an RxSwift update (3.4.0). My code updated Variable value in concurrent queue. Changed to serial queue fixed this crash.

Thierry

Answer (score 1):

You can have the same behavior without using the `Variable`.

```
    let scheduler = SerialDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .userInitiated)
    NotificationCenter.default.rx.notification(MyNotificationName)
        .take(9)
        .observeOn(scheduler)
        .subscribe(onNext: { _ in
            let noti = Notification(name: MyNotificationName)
            print("foo")
            NotificationCenter.default.post(noti)
        }).disposed(by: bag)

    let noti = Notification(name: MyNotificationName)
    NotificationCenter.default.post(noti)
```

Comment: Can you double check your answer? I tried and it didn't work.

Comment: Define "work" in this context. What is it that you want to do?

Comment: My code can't possibly trigger the fatal error, it doesn't even use the Sink class. Again I ask, what is it you are trying to do? I seriously doubt that you are merely trying to put 1 through 10 in a textView, nor do I think you are trying to send 10 identical notifications...

Comment: Just adding 'NotificationCenter.default.post(noti)' new line behind your code block to trigger the notification manually, you will get the fatal error on the 'post' line in your block. You didn't get fatal error yourself because your code block never runs before.

Comment: Thanks @OwenZhao. I have updated my answer to avoid the error.

Answer (score 1):

I have mark @thierryb 's answer as the correct one. The known correct answers are as below.

```
NotificationCenter.default.rx.notification(MyNotificationName)
    .observeOn(MainScheduler.asyncInstance)
    .subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] _ in
        if self.v.value == 10 { self.notiBag = DisposeBag() }
        else { self.v.value += 1 } // this line cause the issue
        print(self.v.value)
        self.counterTextView.text! += "\(self.v.value)\n"
    })
    .disposed(by: notiBag)
```

or

```
NotificationCenter.default.rx.notification(MyNotificationName)
    .subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] _ in
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
            if self.v.value == 10 { self.notiBag = DisposeBag() }
            else { self.v.value += 1 } // this line cause the issue
            print(self.v.value)
            self.counterTextView.text! += "\(self.v.value)\n"
        }
    })
    .disposed(by: notiBag)
```